# LeapMotion AS3 Find Index Finger

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, leap-motion

Is there currently a way to always guarantee which finger is being tracked with the LeapMotion AS3 Library? I only want to track the index finger.

My example below only works when clenching your fist and really exaggerating your index finger as the one you want being tracked. If I loosen my fist, sometimes it grabs my thumb as the index finger.

```
if ( fingers.length > 0 ) {
     var indexFinger:Finger = fingers[0];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use finger.type == Finger.TYPE_INDEX? How reliably does that work?

Comment: Maybe you should get the size of each finger then calculate which finger's size should be the index finger's?

Answer (score 0):

In version 1 of the Leap Motion SDK, there is no guarantee that the finger list will be in any particular order and the finger at index 0 could be any finger. In version 2, the fingers are always present and always in order: 0-4, thumb-pinky. If you are using v1 libraries with the v2 service install, you will get the v1 behavior.